# How to get Bluetooth permission for migrated Maui app in iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, maui

I'm migrating a Xamarin.Forms app to MAUI, so my solution still has:

Shared project

Android project

iOS project

My iOS project had all requirement to ask the user for Bluetooth permission,

meaning all required strings in info.plist:

```
NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription

NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription

Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description

Privacy - Bluetooth Always Usage Description
```

permission service in shared project and providers in each platform.

The iOS provider create the CBCentralManager instance,
and upon creation the user is supposed to get the alert asking for Bluetooth permission:

```
public async Task<bool> RequestBluetoothPermission()
{
   var manager = new CBCentralManager(null, null, new CBCentralInitOptions { });
   var state = manager.State == CBManagerState.PoweredOn;
}
```

In my migrated app, this does not happen on iOS.

The manager is created, its state is CBManagerState.Unknown, and the alert doesn't show.

Does anyone know how get the migrated Maui app to ask for Bluetooth permission?

**Update**

The original method used to get Bluetooth permission:

```
public async Task<bool> RequestBluetoothPermission()
    {
        //iOS 13.0 and below
        if (!UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 1))
        {
            return true;
        }

        //iOS 13.1 and above
        if (CBManager.Authorization == CBManagerAuthorization.NotDetermined)
        {
            TaskCompletionSource<CBCentralManagerState> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<CBCentralManagerState>();
            Action<CBCentralManagerState> handleBluetoothStateChangedForFirstTime = delegate (CBCentralManagerState bluetoothState)
           {
               HandleBluetoothStateChanged(bluetoothState);
               tcs.TrySetResult(bluetoothState);
           };

            var simpleCBCentralManagerDelegate = new SimpleCBCentralManagerDelegate();
            simpleCBCentralManagerDelegate.StateChanged += handleBluetoothStateChangedForFirstTime;

            _cBCentralManager = new CBCentralManager(simpleCBCentralManagerDelegate, null, new CBCentralInitOptions() { ShowPowerAlert = false });
            var status = await tcs.Task;

            simpleCBCentralManagerDelegate.StateChanged -= handleBluetoothStateChangedForFirstTime;
            simpleCBCentralManagerDelegate.StateChanged += HandleBluetoothStateChanged;

            return status != CBCentralManagerState.Unauthorized;
        }

        // In any else case we can't ask again so we just return the current permission status
        return CBManager.Authorization == CBManagerAuthorization.AllowedAlways;
    }
```

Comment: You need to create a CBCentralManager that is longer lived. This one will be thrown away once the task ends. You also need to provide a delegate. It will take some time before the delegate gets the state update to `poweredOn`

Comment: May I ask if you run on a simulator or a physical device?

Comment: @Paulw11 I did, but the app would have crashed once the Task was awaited. I have updated the question with full original method.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT Both.

Comment: SImulator does not support bluetooth. And when you initialize ```var manager = new CBCentralManager(null, null, new CBCentralInitOptions { });```, the permission dialog will show and only show once when app first installation, which i made a demo to confirm this.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT That would be fine. I however did not get the dialog even once, also on physical iPhone 11 with iOS 16.

Comment: Have you tried a new Maui  template and add some bluetooth function in it?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT Yes, and apparently it works there, so I found what was wrong, answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the automatic migration tool from Microsoft we used did not take the info.plist in the iOS project and use it.

I should have noticed it earlier because we had several build warning about missing keys in the final file used by MAUI.

This answer lead me on the right path:
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9122#issuecomment-1249177463

I just modified it so:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <BundleResource Include="Info.plist" Link="Info.plist" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Where the info.plist file sits directly under the iOS' project folder.